# Javascript function Call. Escape quotes in strings

Tags: javascript, string, dom-events, literals

Alright and my query is, How do I escape quotes in Javascript? I'm trying to alert the message with my code below. I know it won't work because it contains **string in double quotes** within the `onClick` function call and it gives the syntax error. How do I make it work? My condition is that I cannot use **single quotes** for parameter in my function call.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function litString(vals)
    {
    alert(vals);
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <?php echo "Just for a Test<br/>"; ?>

    <a href="#" onClick="litString("test one")"><h2>JS String Literal</h2></a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Update:

My actual intention is to make the below PHP+JS code combination work:

```
 echo '<li><a href="#" title="'.$res_bb['eng'].'" onClick=loadChap('.$res_bb['id'].','.$res_bb['chapters'].',"'.$res_bb['mal'].'")><font size="2">'.$res_bb['mal'].'</font></a></li>';
```

Comment: Why can't you use single quotes?'

Comment: The entire anchor tag is already in PHP's echo in single quote!

Comment: No it isn't. The only thing being echoed is `"Just for a Text<br/>"`.

Comment: And if it is in an echo, you can escape the single quotes to keep it from breaking PHP.

Comment: @Barmar this is my entire PHP,Js code.                             echo '<li><a href="#" title="'.$res_bb['eng'].'" onClick=loadChap('.$res_bb['id'].','.$res_bb['chapters'].',"'.$res_bb['mal'].'")><font size="2">'.$res_bb['mal'].'</font></a></li>';

Comment: Code in comments is unreadable. Update your question.

Comment: @Barmar Just updated. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28185/discussion-between-jenson-m-john-and-barmar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You escape quotes with backslash `\`.

```
<a href="#" onClick="litString(\"test one\")"><h2>JS String Literal</h2></a>
```

Or you can use single quotes:

```
<a href="#" onClick="litString('test one')"><h2>JS String Literal</h2></a>
```

Or you can use single quotes around the attribute, and double quotes inside:

```
<a href="#" onClick='litString("test one")'><h2>JS String Literal</h2></a>
```

If you're echoing the string, it gets a little trickier, because you also have to deal with PHP's quoting. Here I produce the second version above by escaping the single quotes.

```
echo '<li><a href="#" title="'.$res_bb['eng'].'" onClick="loadChap('.$res_bb['id'].','.$res_bb['chapters'].',\''.$res_bb['mal'].'\')"><font size="2">'.$res_bb['mal'].'</font></a></li>';
```

I just tested this with input:

```
$res_bb = array('eng'=> "Title", 'id'=> 10, 'chapters'=> 13, 'mal'=> "Foo bar");
```

The output was:

```
<li><a href="#" title="Title" onClick="loadChap(10,13,'Foo bar')"><font size="2">Foo bar</font></a></li>
```

Comment: I Cannot use your 2nd & 3rd solution because my condition is juz like that. & My Intention was only to apply with your FIRST solution. But That didn't work @ all..:( Can you Just verify?

Comment: In your comment above, you mentioned that this is in a PHP echo, although that's not how it appears in the question. If that's the case, you need to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener) and `data-*` attributes [for a cleaner approach](http://jsfiddle.net/SK2LQ/1/):

```
<a href="#" id="someButton" data-litString="test one">...

<script>
  var link = document.getElementById('someButton');

  link.addEventListener('click', function () {
    var vals = this.getAttribute('data-litString');
    alert(vals);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: <a href="#" onClick="litString(\"test one\")"><h2>JS String Literal</h2></a> Does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Use single quotes for the HTML attribute:

```
onClick='litString("test one")'
```

But that's not really a solution. You need to escape those double quotes somehow.

Comment: I cannot use  single quotes for the HTML attribute because already anchor tag in PHP's single quote.! @barmar has given 2 more methods & I just want to use his first method but that didn't work @ all! :(

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's better to go this way...

```
<li><a href="#" title="<?php echo $res_bb['eng']; ?>" onClick=loadChap("<?php echo $res_bb['id']; ?>", "<?php echo $res_bb['chapters']; ?>"," <?php echo $res_bb['mal']; ?>")><font size="2"><?php echo $res_bb['mal']; ?></font></a></li>
```

Comment: It returned with some parse Error. Anyway that got it worked with Barmar's updated solution. Thanks.